# Login to Salesforce from .NET

Tags: single-sign-on

I tried to login to as salesforce community user from a .NET application "https://perfectvisionpoe--pvccdevorg.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/55.0/_____" API callout but I am able to get the session id for internal user not for community user. For internal user I am able to login with session id but I need to login as salesforce community user from .NET application. Do we have another solution like OpenID Connect and its implementation support for both Salesforce and .NET end. My business flow is customer will login to .NET web site and once the customer clicks on a link they will be redirected to community page with out entering login details into salesforce community portal.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_authentication_options.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...my.salesforce.com/services/soap/c/55.0/...` is an internal org URL. To use a community with SSO, you need to use that community's domain and path. You can read more about that in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_between_multiple_orgs.htm&type=5).